How to show text which was made by text editor (inluce html tag) when using PDFKit
I'm using PDFKit, in the documents the example code is:
const lorem = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam in suscipit purus.  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vivamus nec hendrerit felis. Morbi aliquam facilisis risus eu lacinia. Sed eu leo in turpis fringilla hendrerit. Ut nec accumsan nisl.';

doc.fontSize(8);
doc.text(`This text is left aligned. ${lorem}`, {
  width: 410,
  align: 'left'
}
);

But I have an issue: If the init text includes html tag (because I'm using a text editor for this field), the code will be:
const lorem = '<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
<strong>industry</strong>.</p><p><br></p><p><em>Lorem Ipsum has been the
industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took
a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</em></
p><p><br></p><p>It has survived not <u>only five centuries</u>, but also the leap
into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p><p><br></
p><ul><li>It was popularised in the 1960s</li><li>with the release of Letraset sheets
containing Lorem Ipsum passages</li><li>and more recently with desktop</li></
ul><p><br></p><p>publishing <strong><em><u>software like Aldus </u></em></
strong></p><p><br></p><p><strong><em><u><span class="ql-cursor"> </span></
u></em></strong>PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>';

doc.fontSize(8);
doc.text(`This text is left aligned. ${lorem}`, {
  width: 410,
  align: 'left'
}
);

How can I format this text. If it was a client-side I can apply this code to solve:
 <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `${lorem}` }}
      className={classNames("truncate whitespace-pre-line", className)}
 />

but for now I'm using PDFKit on the server-side of nextjs. Is there any way to fix this issue?
